# Error: no such file or directory: '–std=c++11' after compiling makefile

Tags: c++, c++11, compilation, makefile

When I compile using `make` in the terminal it prints:

```
g++ -Wall –std=c++11 -c File.cpp
clang: error: no such file or directory: '–std=c++11'
make: *** [Book.o] Error 1
```

makefile:

```
PROG = studs
CC = g++
OBJS = File.o FileTestDriver.o
CPPFLAGS = -Wall –std=c++11

$(PROG) : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $(PROG) $(OBJS)
File.o : File.h
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c File.cpp
FileTestDriver.o :
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) -c FileTestDriver.cpp
clean:
    $(RM) $(PROG) $(OBJS)
```

*FileTestDriver* has the main function and *File.cpp* is just a simple class with some constructors, instance variables and functions. I'm not sure where the problem is but I assume it's in the Makefile as I just started using them today.

When I simply compile `g++ -std=c++11 File.cpp` I get the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

But I assume the error is because it has a `.h` and needs the makefile to be compiled. Anyway, not sure what I'm doing wrong but I appreciate any help. Let me know if more info is needed.

Also (maybe this should be a separate question/I need to look harder), but after using the makefile, `./a.out` will only ever run the makefile, regardless of the last thing I compiled. Not sure how to change that.

Comment: It looks "g++" is actually invoking `clang` on your system. What happens if you do `g++ --version` from the command line? clang's command line should be compatible with gcc's, but you might need a newer version than what you have.

Comment: Actually... it looks like your `-std` has an em-dash, not a normal ASCII hyphen. Try re-typing it in your Makefile, and make sure you're not using a fancy text editor that replaces `-` with some kind of fancy character.

Comment: Wow that was it, thank you. I think I copied and pasted but I would have never thought that was a thing.

Comment: @notmyfriend: actually, it's an en dash rather than an em, but your comment is still valid, it's *not* the hyphen-minus it needs to be :-)

Comment: Also on the `gcc/clang` note, I seem to recall that Macs had a `gcc` command that was just a hard/symbolic link through to `clang`. This may be what's causing the `clang` output from a `gcc` invocation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you take a look at your compile line *closely,* you'll see a very subtle difference between the `-` before `Wall` and the `–` before `std=c++11`:

```
g++ -Wall –std=c++11 -c File.cpp
    ^     ^
```

Here are those two options, one under the other, captured with Windows Snipping Tool and blown up with Paint.net. You can clearly see that the second "hyphen" is wider:

[image]

And it's wider because it's *not* a hyphen - the character is actually an `en dash` (Unicode code point `U+2013`).

This problem is often caused by cutting and pasting directly from places like word processors<sup>(a)</sup> or web pages. Because it's not considered a valid lead-in character (`hyphen-minus`, or Unicode code point `U+002D`), it's simply being treated as a file name, hence the error.

I suggest you just retype the line (or only the `-std=c++11` bit) to ensure it's using the correct character.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Word processors, with their smart text replacement features, will often turn hyphens into en- or em- dashes, or modify your strings or character literals from `"pax"` into `“pax”`. You can disable this behaviour (smart quotes in MS Word, for example) but it's sometimes quite handy.

I just tend to avoid using word processors as text editors, or become aware to the possibility that cut'n'pasted code may contain "suspicious" character. If a piece of text I've gotten from the web or a word processor causes my build system to complain, I examine (and retype manually) the offending section.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake as follows:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std = c++11")
```

Notice there is **NO** whitespace between `-std` and `c++11`